# jQuery quit animation before starting a new animation

Tags: jquery, animation

I have:

```
$('.p_m').mouseenter(function () {

    $(this).animate({
        marginTop: '10px',
        marginLeft: '10px',
        height: '150px',
        width: '150px'
    }, 10000);

}).mouseleave(function () {

    $(this).animate({
        marginTop: '35px',
        marginLeft: '35px',
        height: '100px',
        width: '100px'
    }, 10000);
});
```

When I leave the class `'.p_m'` quicker than 10000ms, the mouseenter animation keeps going even if I leave the div class.

How can I skip the animation (mouseenter) or better make it fast so it fits to 10000ms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`.stop()`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) to halt the current animation.

```
$('.p_m').mouseenter(function () {

    $(this).stop().animate({
        marginTop: '10px',
        marginLeft: '10px',
        height: '150px',
        width: '150px'
    }, 10000);

}).mouseleave(function () {

    $(this).stop().animate({
        marginTop: '35px',
        marginLeft: '35px',
        height: '100px',
        width: '100px'
    }, 10000);
});
```

If you want the animation to skip to the end before starting the new one, pass `true` as the second argument. `.stop(true,true)`